# Raspberry Pi screen blanking when playing multimedia

Tags: pi-4

My Raspberry Pi is a Pi 4 Model B.

The screen blanks out whenever I am doing the following:

1. Running Zoom
2. Clicking to play a YouTube video
3. Running Google Meet
4. Playing a music from SoundCloud

Basically it seems like the screen will blank itself out whenever I do something that has video or sound. I have already set my GPU to 256. I have tried 128 too.

Any solution or hint is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this by switching from HDMI to the audio jack for sound.